# Google Sheets | how to use script to filter by more than one column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use the script below to filter by columnIndex 8 below. Could someone help me figure out how to filter by two columns at the same time?

```
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var filterSettings = {};

  var condition_value = {
    "type": "TEXT_EQ",
    "values": [{"userEnteredValue": "D"}]
  };

  filterSettings.range = {
    sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  };

  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = 8;
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'condition' : condition_value
  };

  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: Is your script latest one? Because I thought that your script of your question might not  work. When you save your script, didn't an error occur?

Comment: I accidentally deleted a line. It should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, when the filter is applied to 7 and 8 of "columnIndex", how about modifying as follows?

#### From :

```
filterSettings.criteria = {};
var columnIndex = 8;
filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
  'condition' : condition_value
};
```

#### To :

```
filterSettings.criteria = {};
var columnIndex1 = 7;
var columnIndex2 = 8;

filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex1] = {
  'condition' : condition_value
};

filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex2] = {
  'condition' : condition_value
};
```

#### Note :

- 7 and 8 of "columnIndex" are the column H and I, respectively.

#### Reference :

- [BasicFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets?hl=ja#BasicFilter)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.